# Power supply has no light

Tags: xbox-360

My X-box 360 was working for 7-8 days then suddenly my 360 did something really weird. I was playing Warface and joining a party then my x-box just shut off! I tried plugging it in and out but no results. I realized that that the rectangular thing(adapter I think) in between the socket and the X-box used to have a green light and now it had no light at all. Now I'm thinking that the adaptor has something wrong with it because when I plug it in with the power cord it makes a static noise. Now the X-box has my Halo disc in it and wont come out does anybody have any answers???

Comment: It sounds like your power supply was fried. Try finding a local vendor that sells used Xbox 360's and see if they have spares.

Comment: Or if it was only working for 7-8 days then presumably it is still in warranty in which case you should be able to get a free replacement.

Comment: Yeah, it does sound like a blown power supply. Also, this may help you get your Halo disk out - http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/system/manually-eject-disc

Comment: I do have a newer model so the link you gave me ImClarky Did not work.